# Select nearest longitude/latitude values from DB

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with a few thousand positions. These are busstops. What I would like to do is to get the X amount of nearest values to an LON/LAT position.

This is the layout of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buss_StopPoints` (
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LocationNorthing` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LocationEasting` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

These are some example rows:

```
INSERT INTO `buss_StopPoints` (`Name`, `LocationNorthing`, `LocationEasting`) VALUES ('Some station', '59.3195952318672', '18.0717401337168');
INSERT INTO `buss_StopPoints` (`Name`, `LocationNorthing`, `LocationEasting`) VALUES ('Some station 2', '59.3195772927918', '18.0717389396547');
INSERT INTO `buss_StopPoints` (`Name`, `LocationNorthing`, `LocationEasting`) VALUES ('Some station 3', '59.3234014331742', '18.0671617033088');
INSERT INTO `buss_StopPoints` (`Name`, `LocationNorthing`, `LocationEasting`) VALUES ('Some station 4', '59.3233921590479', '18.0671786573678');
INSERT INTO `buss_StopPoints` (`Name`, `LocationNorthing`, `LocationEasting`) VALUES ('Some station 5', '59.3313179695727', '18.061677395945');
```

My question: How can I make a select statement that selects the nearest X amount of rows from the DB, both in negative and positive direction. (e.g. lets say I ask for 59.3234014331742,18.0671617033088 and want the nearest 4 stations, which is this case should return all).

Comment: What about using a DB with GIS functions, like Postgres' PostGIS addon, or a similar addon that exists for MySQL?  Check Spatial Extensions in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: MySQL has good fairly support for [spatial searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html). Have you considered using that?

Comment: No to both, I have not considered that... or even hear of them. I'll have a look. How would that work?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a numeric in type of columns, rename columns to longtitude, latitude. It may distract responders from giving you best answer. Is use of varchar a requirement ? And math wise. I'd start with Pithagorian formula and use it in select

Comment: The naming and setup of columns comes from the external API that delivers the data, I feel it is best to support their documentation so I do not get any problems later on, and so the use of data between my DB and the datasource doesn't get confusing.

Comment: @Filburt Those whom are closest to the requested longitude/latitude position, defined in lon/lat calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LAT = latitude value
LON = longitude value

SELECT Name, (6371 * acos( cos( radians(LAT) ) * cos( radians( LocationNorthing ) ) * cos( radians( LON ) - radians(LocationEasting) ) + sin( radians(LAT) ) * sin( radians(LocationNorthing) ) )) AS distance order by distance
```